# Cuepoints play button not playing video on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, html5-video

Hi I am using this small script to create cuepoints for my video:

```
(function(a){a.fn.cuepoints=function(c){var e=this[0];var d={};function b(){d=a.extend({},c)}b();e.addEventListener("playing",b);e.addEventListener("ended",b);e.addEventListener("loadstart",b);e.addEventListener("seeked",b);e.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(){for(var g in d){var f=parseFloat(g,10);g=g+"";if(f<=e.currentTime&&e.currentTime<=f+0.5){d[g]();delete d[g]}}});return this}})(jQuery);
```

The problem I am facing is my button will play the video on the `first` click just fine and when the cuepoint is reached the video pauses however when I press the play button a `second` time the video will not play (even though the console confirms it has been clicked twice) but if I click the button a `third` time the video will play again any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video"); 
 $(document).on('click touchstart tap', '.nextSlide', function() {
      vid.play();
      console.log('Clicked');     
        });

   $('#video').cuepoints({
        10.5: function () {
          vid.pause();
        },
        15: function() {

        }
     });
```

Comment: This looks like a bug with the `$.cuepoints` plugin. If you got that code from somewhere like GitHub, you may want to open an issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

The `$.cuepoints()` plugin keeps track of all the times and callbacks in an object: `{10.5: function() {...}, ...}`. Whenever the video's `timeupdate` event fires, the plugin looks at the object, checks to see if the current time is **within half a second range of any of the callback times.** If so, the associated function is executed and the entry is removed.

However, if someone were to rewind the video, there has to be a way to run those functions at the specified times again. To handle that, the plugin listens for `playing`, `ended`, `loadstart`, and `seeked` events. When any of those events occur, **the time and callback object gets reset.**

So here's your problem: when you run `vid.pause()` in your callback function, the video stops. When the user unpauses video, the `playing` event fires, resetting all the callbacks. Almost immediately, a `timeupdate` event realizes that you're still within the half second period, and calls your callback function yet again.

In point of fact, it *doesn't* always play on the third click. Sometimes it takes four clicks, because the `timeupdate` event keeps firing inside that half-second period.

Now, the half-second range is necessary. You [don't get any guarantee of how often the `timeupdate` is going to fire](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate), so if you don't have something like that, you run a good chance of skipping the callbacks altogether.

My solution is to stop listening to `playing` events. The time/event object gets set up when the plugin is originally called, so the first play work fine. When users use the meter to move to a different time, the `seeked` event will fire. When users get to the end and decide to replay it, the `ended` event will already have fired. I don't think that the `playing` event is necessary.

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/zxfzjqu2/

Comment: What seemed to do the trick in my case is changing currentTime<=f+0.5 to 0.1 and it seems to be working fine now, however I will mark this as correct as this seems to be working, thanks